# Changing text using class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to change the text of all points having a class name as child.

Tried the below code but it is not changing.

```js
function myFunction() {

  document.getElementsByClassName("child").innerHTML = "Milk";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <ul class="example">
    <li class="child">Coffee</li>
    <li class="child">Tea</li>
  </ul>


  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click here!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all the elements with specific selector you can use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then loop through all the element to set the content.

**Please Note:** If the value to be set is text then it is better to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".child").forEach(function(li){
    li.textContent = "Milk";
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <ul class="example">
    <li class="child">Coffee</li>
    <li class="child">Tea</li>
  </ul>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click here!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of HTMLElements.
So you can not use `innerHTML` instantly.

You need to iterate over the array, for example like so:

```
var eles = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
for (var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
    eles[i].innerHTML = 'Milk';
}
```